# Puppeteer downloaded files location with Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to click on a button and download that trigger the download of a pdf file.

Everything works fine on local but when the app is running on a Heroku server, I can't find the location of the PDF file.

I tried changing the default downloading folder with :

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: my_path});
```

But I can't find my file in the Heroku app.

My question is : does puppeteer actually save files when downloading on a Heroku app ? (I don't care if the file is temporary). If yes, how can I choose the emplacement ? Or how can I access the files in nodeJS ?

Thanks.